# how to solved charmap' codec can't encode character '\u300b?

Tags: python, windows, mingw, termux, charmap

I'm trying to start a script,  but I have run in to a problem.
[ERROR]  'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u300b' in position 11: character maps to

Comment: Hey there, welcome to StackOverflow. While we understand that you're trying to decode some string in Python, we don't really know what you're doing in code and can only guess what's going on. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is printing something that is unreadable for the machine. Try changing the output encoding to "utf-8" or just use code below at the very first lines of your code:

```py
import sys
sys.stdin.reconfigure(encoding='utf-8')
sys.stdout.reconfigure(encoding='utf-8')
```